# How to change the shapes of the corners of textview, button, edit text by applying themes dynamically?

Tags: android, android-widget, styles, themes

This is my code. I have never seen any changes in my application. I have created this in `resources/drawable`. How should I apply themes in a style dynamically for all components by changing text `color`, `fonts`, `shapes` etc.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shape="oval" android:padding="20dp">
     <solid android:color="#FFA500"/>
     <corners android:bottomRightRadius="50dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="50dp"
     android:topLeftRadius="50dp" android:topRightRadius="50dp"/>
     <stroke android:color="#FFA500" android:dashWidth="50dp" />
 </shape>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code above works absolutely fine. Maybe the problem is with the way you declared the background: are you doing it in XML file or dynamically by Java code?

Comment: Not dynamically, since i have noticed themes /styles doesnt support dynamically. So i am working in Xml.

Comment: ok..just saw your code...just try declaring the background dynamically.. Button button=(Button)findviewbyid(r.id.yourid);
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yourxmlfile);...i think code works for you

Comment: yes, i have noticed. It has been changed especially button shape. But i should not call it in Java (Activity). I need to do this in an Xml file. When i call theme, it must be applied dynamically to all the buttons in my app entirely.

Comment: your background code works fine in my xml file too.i think there is some problem with your @style/theme...post the theme code

Answer (score 1):

Create an shape.xml in drawable

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
     android:shape="rectangle">
 <gradient
    android:startColor="#99CCFF"
    android:endColor="#99CCFF"
    android:angle="45"/>
 <padding android:left="6dp"
    android:top="6dp"
    android:right="6dp"
    android:bottom="6dp" />
 <corners android:radius="30dp" />
 </shape>
```

Now for your Button code add android:background as shown below.

```
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/bt"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/shape"/>  // shape is name of xml file created
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval" android:padding="20dp">
<padding android:left="6dp"
android:top="6dp"
android:right="6dp"
android:bottom="6dp" />
<gradient
android:startColor="#FFA500"
android:endColor="#FFA500"
android:angle="45"/>
<solid android:color="#FFA500"/>
<corners android:bottomRightRadius="50dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="50dp"
android:topLeftRadius="50dp" android:topRightRadius="50dp"/>
<stroke 
android:color="#FFA500"
android:dashWidth="50dp"/>  //created shape in res/drawable

Comment: <Button
         style="@style/CustomTheme"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textColor="#808000"
         android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
        android:text="Button" /> //Created in Main.xml